# Create signal that doesn't return a value

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

How can you create a signal that doesn't return any value? I just want to know when the signal has completed.

I tried using `Signal<AnyObject?, NSError>` but I get a lot of type inference errors.

Comment: Can you simply use `Void` as the type?

Comment: Still getting type inference error

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to remove one of the type parameters when I changed it to void, it's not fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply use `Void` as the type. There is only one possible value: `()`.

Comment: Actually, `Void` and `()` are identical, there is no real value of `Void`, it just means that there is not type

Comment: Void is defined as `typealias Void = ()`. But `()` is *both* a type and a value. `let x: ()` and `let x = ()` are both valid.

Comment: Whops right, totally forgot for a moment that `()` is actually an empty tuple, so it is a type and a value :D